# Ignoring overload of swap function

Tags: c++, stl

I overloaded swap function for my class as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2684544/5538150), but while sorting (`std::sort`) compiler is still using `std::swap`. I don't see any difference between my approach and the one stated in linked answer. Here's reproduction of my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
struct A
{
    friend void swap(A & a, A & b)
    {
        std::swap(a.a, b.a);
        std::cout << "my swap\n";   
    }

    A(int _a) : a(_a) {}
    bool operator<(const A & other) { return a < other.a; }
    int a;
};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<B::A> v{1, 2, 3, 5, 4};
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

Also executable example provided [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KZ5Aclm2TDA76oPB).

Comment: [This](http://eel.is/c++draft/utility.requirements#swappable.requirements-3.2) might be relevant: _"It is unspecified whether a library component that has a swappable requirement includes the header <utility> to ensure an appropriate evaluation context."_

Comment: [Your swap function seems to be correctly called even from inside of `std` namespace.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x6IV0XUtJaPXYPXW). Maybe it is not utilized by `std::sort`.

Comment: Just [pass](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) a function object to std::swap and be done with it.

Comment: @MiroslavVitkov Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Are you positive `std::swap` is being called at all? Additionally, what are you _trying_ to do??

Comment: Actually, after Jodocus's answer, I'm not sure and apparently not

Comment: @txtechhelp I'm trying to sort a vector in a way that exchanging elements (swapping) isn't exacly swapping but something slightly different

Comment: @Criss Overload the move/copy assignment/constructor

Comment: @PasserBy Nope, unfortunatelly this doesn't do :/ What I'm actually trying to do is sort one collumn of "two-dimensional vector" (by collumn I mean i.e. `v[0][col], v[1][col], v[2][col] ...`. I don't *need* this, just for fun. Here's what currently done (including your proposition): [click](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qBOOSj5nPNzdvt0z)

Answer (score 2):

The standard doesn't state in its specification (§25.4.1.1 [alg.sort]) that `std::sort` actually is guaranteed to call `swap`, it only mentions that the type must fulfill certain concepts which I wouldn't interpret as a guarantee:

> Requires:
>   RandomAccessIterator
>   shall satisfy the requirements of
>   ValueSwappable
>   (17.6.3.2). The
>   type of
>   *first
>   shall satisfy the requirements of
>   MoveConstructible
>   (Table 20) and of
>   MoveAssignable
>   (Table 22).

It therefore rather just *may* call it, depending on the implementation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219525/does-stl-sort-use-swap-or-binary-copy) may also provide some information on that.

Comment: You might want to back up your claim, a speculation isn't a great answer. The linked post is 6 years old now, and things may have changed.

Comment: Well, proving something does not exist is a tricky thing. I cannot prove the non-existence of Russell's teapot, either. § 25.4.1.1 [alg.sort] does not state that it is using `swap`, it is only requiring `Swapable`. I wouldn't take that as a proof, but as an indication that `sort` not necessarily can get injected by a custom `swap`.

Comment: The ideal answer would be "the standard places no restrictions on how `std::sort` swaps things", which is proven by exhaustively going through the standard.